# Python typing: function argument interdependence

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Take this function from Django Rest Framework [source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0323d6f8955f987771269506ca5da461e2e7a248/rest_framework/relations.py#L20-L26):

```py
def method_overridden(method_name, klass, instance):
    """
    Determine if a method has been overridden.
    """
    method = getattr(klass, method_name)
    default_method = getattr(method, '__func__', method)  # Python 3 compat
    return default_method is not getattr(instance, method_name).__func__
```

The function is intended to determine if a method has been overridden by a subclass and accepts a type `klass` and an object `instance`. In context, `instance` is meant to be a subclass of `klass`, however, the function only really cares that they both have a method  `method_name`.

So that example has led me to try to solve a more general case, how can you express an interdependence between arguments of a function such that one argument should be an instance of another argument that is a type, without actually caring what that type is?
I tried this:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def fn(t: type[T], i: T) -> None:
    pass

fn(dict, "str")  # no mypy error
```

Using a class, you can bind the type to the class:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

class K(Generic[T]):
    def meth(self, t: type[T], i: T) -> None:
        pass

K[dict]().meth(dict, "str")  # Argument 2 to "meth" of "K" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Dict[Any, Any]"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mypy` infers `T` in such a way that both arguments can match. We can check that by redefining `fn` slightly:

```
def fn(t: type[T], i: T) -> T:
    return i

reveal_type(fn(dict, "str"))  # -> Collection[Any]
reveal_type(fn(int, "str"))  # -> object
```

To solve this you can either force `T` to be a specific type (like you did) or separate the arguments and force `mypy` to first infer `T` for one of the arguments.

```
def fn2(t: type[T]) -> Callable[[T], None]:
    def inner(i: T) -> None:
        pass
    return inner

fn2(dict)("str")  # error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "str"; expected "Dict[Any, Any]"
fn2(dict)({})     # no error
fn2(int)(True)    # also no error, because `type` is covariant
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention and explanation. I've not accepted as an answer as I would like to leave it unresolved, especially if there is no way to achieve what I'm asking without refactoring the function. I imagine it would be a hard sell to have a function such as the DRF example in my question to be refactored to support typing it as such.